# WSGI POST request 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache, post, wsgi, http-status-code-403, openstack

Why aren't I able to do a POST request, although GET works?

```
wget --post-data "test" http://10.42.0.1/dashboard
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN
```

Here is my openstack-dashboard.conf

```
WSGIDaemonProcess dashboard
WSGIProcessGroup dashboard
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
WSGIScriptAlias /dashboard /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/django.wsgi
Alias /static /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/static

<Directory /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi>
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/static>
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ /dashboard/
```

Here is the django.wsgi

```
import logging
import os
import sys
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
from django.conf import settings

# Add this file path to sys.path in order to import settings
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '../..'))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'openstack_dashboard.settings'
sys.stdout = sys.stderr

DEBUG = True

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: Is the 403 error generated by Django or Apache. Replace your Django application with a WSGI hello world program to work it out. If Apache, is this in a VirtualHost. Maybe the request isn't even being directed at that VirtualHost.

Comment: I believe it is Apache. I only get the error during a POST request. I did the following with success: (see post 2) http://www.softaculous.com/board/index.php?tid=4514&title=Python_and_mod_wsgi I don't quite understand what you mean about the VirtualHost.

Comment: I was able to do a POST request with a basic WSGI script. http://romania.proximity.on.ca/test.html Hopefully I can find more details about this HTTP error.